# Character constant too long for its type using switch case

Tags: c++, char, switch-statement

I wish to use more then one character in my case statement like the whole 'cosech' like in this program:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <math.h>      
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char select[10];
    cout<<"Enter the value of angle in degrees";float angle;
    cin>>angle;
    cout<<"Choose a trigonometric function \nType cosech for function cosech()";
    cin>>select;
    switch(select[0]<<9)
    {
        case 'cosech':
           cout<<"The cosech of angle "<<angle<<" = "<<1/sinhf(angle);
           break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives the following error

> Line 10 character constant too long for its type

Comment: You could have a map of strings to functions and just call the matching function

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want to happen, in terms of sample input and output? Why do you shift left by 9 in `select[0]<<9`? Do you want to match the whole string or just one of the given characters?

Comment: I think the downvoters should say why - this question is a good question that cuts straight to a common problem with new users

Comment: `'cosech'` is a *multicharacter literal*. It has type `int` and an implementation-defined value, and may not be supported if it's too wide. I've seen multicharacter literals used accidentally more often than they've been used correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. C++, in common with C, does not support using switch statements in this way.

However, that is not the cause of the error. Single quotes `'` are used for character constants, i.e., a single letter. You should use double quotes `"` for string literals. However, this will still not work, as you cannot use a string in a `switch` statement.

Two options are:

1. Come up with single character abbrievations

   ```
   char c;
   cin>>c;
   switch (c)
   {
      case 't':
     //handle tan
     break;
     case 'c':
    //handle cos
   }
   ```

   etc. You could perhaps use lower case and upper case to distinguish between say **t**an and **T**anh
2. Use a chain of if / else if statements, and use `strcmp` to compare the string with your supported options:

   ```
   if(!strcmp(select, "cosech")
   {
       //handle cosech
   }
   else if(!strcmp(select, "tan")
   {
       //handle tan
   }
   ```

etc.

I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with this: `switch(select[0]<<9)`
but it isn't doing what you want.

Comment: please inform me the correct way of doing it i knew it was wrong and thank you for the reply

Comment: should i use if statement then instead of switch or is there any other way to manage somehow And i really appritiacte this quick resposnce (^,^) thank u from the bottom of my hearth

Comment: BTW, another method is to *associate* or *map* a string to a function pointer.  One could also *lookup* the function pointer associated with a string in a lookup table.  Nice advantage:  no `if-else` needed for additional cases.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews agreed. I didn't want to get too advanced though. Walk-before-run and all that - you should those as another answer, or feel free to edit mine

Comment: A post of this website told me that by using (select[0]<<10) or anything other then 10 it runs without any error on that line i can use more then one char at a time with this  for example  i wish to find the decimal place in a char y[]=ABCD but case will check only A,B,C Or D one at a time ; so i tried to use more then one char in my select to use the case more then just one char at a time      But again thank u for the help (^,^) really grateful to you i am building a calculator for my class project and i don,t know advance c++ just the top basics And Thanks____.....

Comment: @Jongware, thanks for the edit - code block wasn't working for me

Answer (score 1):

You should compare strings using the `strcmp()` function, and you should use `if` instead of `case`:

```
    #include < iostream>     
    #include  <math.h>      
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        char select[10];
        cout<<"Enter the value of angle in degrees";float angle;
        cin>>angle;
        cout<<"Choose a trigonometric function \nType cosech for function cosech()";
        cin>>select;
        if(strcmp(select, "cosech") == 0)
        {
               cout<<"The cosech of angle "<<angle<<" = "<<1/sinhf(angle);
        }
        else if(strcmp(select, "another func") == 0)
        {
                // calculate another func
        }
        return 0;
    }
```